# "We cannot get a derivative of a function at a point, by taking limits of the derivative at nearby points"?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

my math lecturer said:

"We cannot get a derivative of a function at a point, by taking limits of the derivative at nearby points. We cannot base it on previous calculations"?

What does he mean exactly? I thought the derivative of a function IS the limit of the derivative function AT that point?

eg. derivative of x^2 at 5 = lim (x->5) of 2x

Extremely perplexed!! Kindly explain if possible! Thanks! :D

Comment: Perhaps this will answer your question: how do you *know* the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$?

Comment: The statement is only true if the derivative is continuous.  There are functions with derivatives that are not continuous, in which case you cannot get the value of the derivative by taking the limit of the derivative.

Comment: Hi Clayton, by simple differentiation. But how does this link to my question...

Comment: "I thought the derivative of a function IS the limit of the derivative function AT that point", you see there is a logical problem in this sentence...you can't define something by taking the limit of what you're trying to define.

Answer (score 5):

The function $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c}x^2\sin(1/x), x\ne 0\\0, x=0\end{array}\right.$ has a derivative everywhere.
$f\,'(0)=0$, $f\,'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$
But $f\,'(0)\ne \lim_{x\to 0} f\,'(x)$

Comment: Hi Michael, May I know how you derived \lim_{x\to 0} f\,'(x)$? Is it through one-sided limits? If so, how... thanks in advance... @Michael

Comment: @user2000304 The limit doesn't evene exist, which still means that it doesn't equal $0$.

Comment: Hi Hagen, it does not exist because both one-sided limits are infinite?

Comment: So, 

f'(0) = 0, and,
lim (x->0) of (f'(x)) = infinite, 

Thus, f'(0) =/= lim (x->0) of (f'(x)) ?

Comment: Can someone answer me - May I know if my above comment is correct?